# sed command not replacing a text with newline character

Tags: shell-script, sed, special-characters

The Unix sed command doesn't recognize a backslash escaped n `\n` as a newline character.  For instance, the command `sed  "s!,!\n!g"` is replacing commas in the input text with the letter n and not a newline character.

How can I make sed interpret `\n` as a newline character?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `bash`, you can insert the newline character by hitting the enter key as

```
sed 's!,!\
!g'
```

Comment: That dint work either

Comment: oops my appologies . This is working :

Answer (score 2):

`sed "s/,/\n/g"` works here, in bash

Answer (score 2):

The Mac version of sed has this difficulty. Try installing the GNU version of sed with `brew install coreutils` and then

```
gsed "s/,/\\n/g"
```

should work. Alternatively, `tr ',' \\n` should work if the search string is only a single character.

Comment: This worked on my Mac (Catalina), but I had to install gnu-sed, not coreutils using brew.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape it with a second `\`

`sed 's!,!\\n!g'`

You may also need to replace out some white space, depending on what you are looking to do.

in my tests as well sed took issue to using `"`'s instead of `'`'s

Comment: Then it replaces a , with \n string not character. Not working either :(

Comment: Hmm this worked for a redhat 6.7 machine, what is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Unix Echo + Sed not always process \n as new line character.
I've solved it by providing carriage return ASCII 0xd with vertical tab ASCII 0xb instead.

For example add new line character with sed command using variable:

```
eol="\xd\xb"
echo -e "hello" | sed "s/$/$eol/"
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.